# How to reduce the dimensions of a numpy array by using the sum over n elements?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have the following array (numbers are placeholders for illustration):

```
arr = np.array([[1,  1,  1,    2,  2,  2,    3,  3,  3,    4  ,4,  4 ],
                [1,  1,  1,    2,  2,  2,    3,  3,  3,    4,  4,  4 ],
                [1,  1,  1,    2,  2,  2,    3,  3,  3,    4,  4,  4 ],

                [5,  5,  5,    6,  6,  6,    7,  7,  7,    8,  8,  8 ],
                [5,  5,  5,    6,  6,  6,    7,  7,  7,    8,  8,  8 ],
                [5,  5,  5,    6,  6,  6,    7,  7,  7,    8,  8,  8 ],

                [9,  9,  9,    10, 10, 10,   11, 11, 11,   12, 12, 12],
                [9,  9,  9,    10, 10, 10,   11, 11, 11,   12, 12, 12],
                [9,  9,  9,    10, 10, 10,   11, 11, 11,   12, 12, 12],

                [13, 13, 13,   14, 14, 14,   15, 15, 15,   16, 16, 16],
                [13, 13, 13,   14, 14, 14,   15, 15, 15,   16, 16, 16],
                [13, 13, 13,   14, 14, 14,   15, 15, 15,   16, 16, 16]])
```

I would like to reduce the dimensions in a way that every 9 elements (3x3 area) having the same numer here would be summed up. So the 12*12 array should become a 4x4 array.

I was looking here for other answers and have found something for a 1D array I adapted.
Hoewever, it is not working as expected:

```
result = np.sum(arr.reshape(-1,3), axis=1)
result = np.sum(result .reshape(3,-1), axis=0)
```

What is the correct was to achieve the desrired result?

Comment: Does each "square" have unique values, as in the example?

Comment: The question linked by @MykolaZotko contains the partial answer, but for this case I think we need strides, as included in my answer below.

Comment: The question asks about something else. They are linked, in terms of how they can be solved, but they ask different things @MykolaZotko

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If we look at the flattened array

```
arr.ravel()
# array([ 1,  1,  1,  2,  2,  2,  3,  3,  3,  4,  4,  4,  1,  1,  1,  2,  2,
#         2,  3,  3,  3,  4,  4,  4,  1,  1,  1,  2,  2,  2,  3,  3,  3,  4,
#         4,  4,  5,  5,  5,  6,  6,  6,  7,  7,  7,  8,  8,  8,  5,  5,  5,
#         6,  6,  6,  7,  7,  7,  8,  8,  8,  5,  5,  5,  6,  6,  6,  7,  7,
#         7,  8,  8,  8,  9,  9,  9, 10, 10, 10, 11, 11, 11, 12, 12, 12,  9,
#         9,  9, 10, 10, 10, 11, 11, 11, 12, 12, 12,  9,  9,  9, 10, 10, 10,
#        11, 11, 11, 12, 12, 12, 13, 13, 13, 14, 14, 14, 15, 15, 15, 16, 16,
#        16, 13, 13, 13, 14, 14, 14, 15, 15, 15, 16, 16, 16, 13, 13, 13, 14,
#        14, 14, 15, 15, 15, 16, 16, 16])
```

We can see a pattern

1. Groups of `3` digits
2. in groups of `4`
3. in super-groups of `3`

Use that to reshape your array (from back to front), and take the sum

```py
arr.reshape(-1, 3, 4, 3).sum((-1, -3))
# array([[  9,  18,  27,  36],
#        [ 45,  54,  63,  72],
#        [ 81,  90,  99, 108],
#        [117, 126, 135, 144]])
```

Comment: Maybe that 4 can be obtained knowing the block size? `arr.shape[0]//3`?

Answer (score 3):

I suggest following [Nils' answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64663129/7089239), as it is simpler and more efficient for this particular case, although what I suggest below is more general, if you wanted something else than just a sum.

---

You are looking for *[convolution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convolution)*. A small kernel is run over the array, performing element-wise multiplications and summing the results, generating values at each step for a new array. In this case we want a simple sum, so we'll use a kernel of ones with the appropriate size (3x3). Because we want no overlap, our *stride* is also 3 in both directions.

2D convolution is not available in NumPy, so we'll have to import from SciPy. But that function doesn't have stride (skipping) functionality, so we'll implement our own manually.

```py
from scipy.signal import convolve2d

kernel = np.ones((3, 3))
convolved = convolve2d(arr, kernel, mode='valid')
strided = convolved[::3, ::3]
```

`strided` contains the result here, and we can check the final result by dividing by nine, to get the original value of each cell.

```py
>>> strided / 9
array([[ 1.,  2.,  3.,  4.],
       [ 5.,  6.,  7.,  8.],
       [ 9., 10., 11., 12.],
       [13., 14., 15., 16.]])
```

Answer (score 1):

after a bit fiddling with `reshape`, I came up with this

```py
arr = np.array([[ 1,  1,  1,  2,  2,  2,  3,  3,  3,  4,  4,  4],
        [ 1,  1,  1,  2,  2,  2,  3,  3,  3,  4,  4,  4],
        [ 1,  1,  1,  2,  2,  2,  3,  3,  3,  4,  4,  4],
        [ 5,  5,  5,  6,  6,  6,  7,  7,  7,  8,  8,  8],
        [ 5,  5,  5,  6,  6,  6,  7,  7,  7,  8,  8,  8],
        [ 5,  5,  5,  6,  6,  6,  7,  7,  7,  8,  8,  8],
        [ 9,  9,  9, 10, 10, 10, 11, 11, 11, 12, 12, 12],
        [ 9,  9,  9, 10, 10, 10, 11, 11, 11, 12, 12, 12],
        [ 9,  9,  9, 10, 10, 10, 11, 11, 11, 12, 12, 12]])

a = np.size(arr,0)//3
b = np.size(arr,1)//3

np.sum(arr.reshape(a, 3, b, 3), axis=(1,3))

# result

array([[  9,  18,  27,  36],
       [ 45,  54,  63,  72],
       [ 81,  90,  99, 108]])
```

Answer (score 0):

We can use `skimage`'s [`view_as_blocks`](https://scikit-image.org/docs/dev/api/skimage.util.html#skimage.util.view_as_blocks) to take a strided view of the array and then take the sum of each block:

```
from skimage.util.shape import view_as_blocks
n = 3
view_as_blocks(arr, (n,n)).sum((-1,2))
array([[  9,  18,  27,  36],
       [ 45,  54,  63,  72],
       [ 81,  90,  99, 108],
       [117, 126, 135, 144]])
```

Comment: Why divide by `n ** 2`? If you want the average, just use `.mean()`. But OP wants to sum, so no normalization necessary. Also you can do `.sum(-1, -2)`

Comment: True, was assuming `mean` for some reason, updated @nils thx

Comment: I think you need a tuple to concatenate axes along which to reduce @nils